# c++ log exception to file, different output

Tags: c++, exception, logging

I want to log an Exception to a file and also send it to console. My problem is that I get an different output.

```cpp
void log(std::string str, std::exception e){
    std::ofstream errorfile;
    errorfile.open("errorlog.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
    errorfile << str << std::endl;
    errorfile << e.what() << std::endl;
    errorfile.close();
}

main()
{
    try
    {
        doSomething();
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::string str = "functionname()";
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        log(str, e);
    }
}
```

Now I get an consoleoutput like:

```
fuctionname()
bind: Address already in use
```

and a different output at the logfile:

```
functionname()
std::exception
```

I recognize that I used `std::cerr` for my consoleoutput, but I don't know how to log with `std::cerr` to a file.

Comment: Of course you do?
You have different code for generating file output and you simple write e.what() to cerr?

Comment: with `std::cerr << e.what;` I get the output I want.

Comment: Ok, but why don't you (for example) use e.what() inside log function then?
Edit:
Ah, you do but you've passed std::exception as copy. Try changing argument of function to `std::exception& e` instead of `std::exception e`. Does it solves your problem?

Comment: I do that. `errorfile << e.what() << std::endl;`

Comment: using a reference worked. thx

Comment: I'm glad I could help. For future try to keep code spinets as short and clear as possible, as in given code it wasn't clear what exactly you wanted to achieve - obviously you printed two different things into file and to cerr :)

Comment: And if you will have troubles understanding why it worked and you are interested in that, read about polymorphic calls, eg here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: Logging with sprintf is so much cleaner an easy to mantain.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `void log(std::string str, std::exception e)`, you create a copy of the exception.

Modify your function to be like `void log(std::string &str, std::exception &e)`

Get a reference on this object to keep the same exception/message and not create a new one with blank fields.

You will increase your performance as well by doing that.